# Ruby: Use key that is stored in TPM

Tags: ruby, ssl, tpm

I'm looking for a way to open a HTTPS connection while the necessary certificates are stored in a TPM.

Right now I am using HTTPClient to open the connection and everything works fine as long as the certificates are stored on disk.

```
  http = HTTPClient.new
  request = "#{address}/#{command}"
  http.ssl_config.set_client_cert_file("#{CLIENT_CERT}",
                                       "#{CLIENT_KEY}")
```

How can I do this if the client private key is stored in a TPM?

Comment: TPM usually don't store certificates. Rather, the TPM stores keys and the keys are used to encrypt data on the file system. Also, the certificate is public information, so it usually does not need protection.

Comment: Updated the question. I want to use a certificate for which the private key part is stored within the TPM

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 possibilities:

- store the key in the TPM's non volatile memory
- 'seal' the file containing the key

To do this in Ruby you can:

- implement the necessary commands yourself and let your code talk to the OS's TPM driver
- write code that uses the C API of [TrouSerS](http://trousers.sourceforge.net/)
- call some command line tools like those provided by [TrouSerS](http://trousers.sourceforge.net/), [jTSS](http://trustedjava.sourceforge.net/index.php?item=jtt/about), or IBM's [tpm_utils](http://ibmswtpm.sourceforge.net/#Utilities)

However, I'm not sure whether that's what you are looking for from an architectural point of view. Loading the key by means of a TPM is only feasible on start-up. If you want to do that for every request it will kill your performance. Besides, you would need to take care that the key is securely wiped from memory, otherwise it would be pointless.